# ThreeJS in IFrame makes mobile browser crash after a few redirection

Tags: javascript, iframe, mobile, three.js

I have ThreeJS based pages that I include via Iframe into another pages: http://krosapp.cz/produktove-3d-modely
Problem is that on a mobile phone (IPhone 7 with just 1GB RAM) switching between the two pages with ThreeJS Iframe (the two links "Bota" and "Brasna") makes browser crash after two or three swithes. Weird thing is that if I go from a page with Iframe directly to a threejs page (no iframe) and then back to a page with threejs in iframe, its working fine. Or if I go from a page with threejs iframe to some vanilla page without threejs and then to a page with threejs iframe, its ok and I can do that multiple times without a problem.
Problem is only when I go from a page with threeJS in Iframe to another page with threejs in iframe.  If I do the same thing with the same threejs scene, but without using Iframes, its ok and I can do it all over again.
Looks like if a  threejs page is in iframe, it somehow will remain in memory after redirecting to another page. Or something like that.
Does anyone has any advice or thoughts why is it like that?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar issue with Three.js keeping in memory on redirections, I think it's a known issue from Three.js. I would recommend you to create a dispose method you can call on redirections to fully dispose all Three.js resources.
This is the one I have in my project (in my case this.world is scene.children[0], you can traverse directly the scene if you want)

```
dispose: async function () {

    //console.log(window.performance.memory);

    return new Promise(disposed => {
        this.world.traverse(function (obj) {
            if (obj.geometry) {
                obj.geometry.dispose();
            }
            if (obj.material) {
                if (obj.material instanceof THREE.MeshFaceMaterial) {
                    obj.material.materials.forEach(function (m) {
                        m.dispose();
                        if (m.map) {
                            m.map.dispose();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    obj.material.dispose();
                }

                let m = obj.material;
                let md = (m.map || m.alphaMap || m.aoMap || m.bumpMap || m.displacementMap || m.emissiveMap || m.envMap || m.lightMap || m.metalnessMap || m.normalMap || m.roughnessMap)
                if (md) {
                    if (m.map) m.map.dispose();
                    if (m.alphaMap) m.alphaMap.dispose();
                    if (m.aoMap) m.aoMap.dispose();
                    if (m.bumpMap) m.bumpMap.dispose();
                    if (m.displacementMap) m.displacementMap.dispose();
                    if (m.emissiveMap) m.emissiveMap.dispose();
                    if (m.envMap) m.envMap.dispose();
                    if (m.lightMap) m.lightMap.dispose();
                    if (m.metalnessMap) m.metalnessMap.dispose();
                    if (m.normalMap) m.normalMap.dispose();
                    if (m.roughnessMap) m.roughnessMap.dispose();
                }
            }
            if (obj.dispose) {
                obj.dispose();
            }
        });
        this.scene.remove(this.world);
        this.scene.dispose();
        this.world.children = [];
        this.world = null;
        this.labelRenderer.dispose();
        this.renderer.dispose();
        disposed('dispose finished');
        //console.log(window.performance.memory);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your snippet. I have tried the very same thing before, but with no luck. Its still the same (and I can see on desktop memory drop after a call to my dispose method, so I would say it should be working) Weird thing is that its a problem only in Iframe. I can understand that memory requirements are higher, as there are basically two pages loaded at the same time, but it makes problem only on redirects - the first load is everytime ok. It makes even Safari debug tools on Mac to crash, so its hard to debug whats going on.